# How to exclude a project from dotnet test run

Tags: xunit, dotnet-test

I have two projects: UnitTests.csproj (xunit) and IntegrationTests.csproj (specflow)

I'm using
`dotnet test MySolution.sln --filter FullyQualifiedName\!~IntegrationTests`
to run unit tests.

However, my IntegrationTests.csproj project contains a method decorated with `[AfterTestRun]` attribute, and it appears that my command runs that method, understandably, even though no tests were run from `IntegrationTests.csproj` project.

I have tried putting `[Category("Integration")]` on the `[AfterTestRun]`-decorated method, but that doesn't seem to be helping.

**Question:** How can I filter test lifecycle methods with dotnet test and xunit?

My workaround is to add the following code to all integration test lifecycle methods:

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_SERVER_URL") is null) return;
```